# How to handle Python Selenium recurring loading modals and stay DRY?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using python 3.6 and selenium 3.8.1, Chrome browser to simulate users entering an order. The app we use has a particularly frustrating implementation for automation - a loading modal will pop up whenever a filter for a product is loading, but it does not truly cover elements underneath it. Additionally, load time fluctuates wildly, but with an upper bound. If I don't use excessive sleep statements, selenium will either start clicking wildly before the correct objects are loaded or clicks on the element but, of course, hits the loading modal. (Fun side note, the loading modal only fills the screen view, so selenium is also able to interact with items below the fold. :P)

To get around this:

```
def kill_evil_loading_modal(self):
    # i pause for a second to make sure the loader has a chance to pop
    time.sleep(1)

    # pulling locator type and from another file: ("id","locator_id")
    loading_modal = ProductsLocators.loading_modal_selector

    # call a function that returns true/false for object if exists
    check_for_evil = self.is_element_exist(*loading_modal)

    while check_for_evil == True:
        check_for_evil = self.is_element_exist(*loading_modal)
```

This works great! Where I had a ton of evil time.sleep(x) statements to avoid the loading modal, I'm now catching it and waiting until it's gone to move forward.

If I only had to deal with that two or three times, I would move on. Sadly, this loading modal hits after *every click* ... so this is what my main script looks like now:

```
 new_quote02_obj.edit_quote_job(**data)
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.click_product_dropdown()
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.click_product_dropdown_link()
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.select_category_dropdown(scenario_data['category_name'])
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.select_market_dropdown(scenario_data['local_sales_market'])
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.add_products_job(scenario_data['product_list_original'])
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.click_done_btn()
 new_quote03_obj.kill_evil_loading_modal()
 new_quote03_obj.next_btn_page()
```

How can I refactor to stay DRY?

Comment: Not necessarily elegant and not looking at the bigger picture, but what about adding the function calls to a dict and then iterating over it (calling the kill_evil_loading_modal function after each).

Comment: @JoeyGrant that's a neat idea. Might not use it here, but will definitely apply that elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait until modal disappeared and avoid using `time.sleep()` you can try [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("id", "locator_id")))
```

or

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(("id", "locator_id")))
```

This should allow you to wait up to 10 seconds (increase delay if needed) until element with specified selector (`"id", "locator_id"`) will become invisible

If modal appears after each click you can implement your own click method, like

```
def click_n_wait(by, value, timeout=10):
    wait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, value))).click()
    wait(driver, timeout).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(("id", "locator_id")))
```

and use it as

```
click_n_wait("id", "button_id")
```

Comment: Wonderful sir. That's **not** DRY though. That's BONE DRY!  :) My syntax in the main script stayed exactly the same, as I implemented click_n_wait under the covers, and I was able to remove my kill modal function completely. Thanks!

Comment: I still had to keep a one sec sleep in between the click and the modal loading. It really seems to be a necessary evil in this case.

Comment: I guess this is because modal window appears not right after you make a click, but with some minimal delay... In this case (only if you're sure that modal appears **after each** click) you can add wait until modal appears `wait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("id", "locator_id")))` as second line in function. So your actions are: 1) Click element, 2) Wait for modal to appear, 3) wait for modal to disappear. With this code you don't need `time.sleep()` at all

Comment: Sweet. I've used all of these ECs, but not chained together effectively and efficiently like this.

Comment: That worked like a charm. No more ugly sleep statements. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question *a loading modal will pop up whenever a filter for a product is loading* irespective of the loader *cover elements underneath it* or not you can simply `wait` for the next intended element with which you want to interact with. Following this approach you can completely get rid of the function `kill_evil_loading_modal()` which looks to me as a overhead. As a replacement to `kill_evil_loading_modal()` function you have to invoke [**WebDriverWait()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) method along with proper [**expected_conditions**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as required as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# other code
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_element_A"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_element_B"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_element_C"))).click()
```

Comment: The problem is that the loading modal can be active _and_ selenium can see and click the other element at the same time. So the EC of wait_til_clickable is passed even though the modal is covering that object.